# automate disable access for a worklight application - GadgetAppID value

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I want to automate the disable access feature of my worklight application ( version :- 6.1.0.2 ) , I have created the below links referring info center links, Can any one please let me know, how can i get the value of gadgetAppID in the below mentioned urls. Also i have added the snap shot of the mysql DB.

```
Disable App post url below. 
http://localhost:10080/AppName/console/api/applications/setAccessRule?gadgetAppId=""&action="disabled"&message="please try later”
Enable App post url below
http://localhost:10080/AppName/console/api/applications/setAccessRule?gadgetAppId=""&action="enabled"&message="please try later”
```

[image]
Thanks
djrekcer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a bit complex in 6.1, see - http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.apiref.doc/admin/r_http_interface_of_the_prod_server.html (search for setAccessRule)

Starting with 6.2 there's a RESTful server API for that, see http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.apiref.doc/apiref/r_restapi_app_version_access_rule_put.html%23App-Version-Access-Rule--PUT-?lang=en

Comment: Hi Anto, I have edited the quesiton to add more information and i would need some clarification, can you please check and help.

Comment: Hi All, Can anyone please check and help on this. Really appreciate your response.